# Profinite topology of a Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a group. Consider now the set of all (left for instance) cosets in $G$ of subgroups of finite index. This set is a base for a topology in $G$.

I found somewhere that if $G$ is residually finite then $G$ is a compact space in this topology but I cannot see why. First of all, is it true? Second, any (maybe more group theoretical) hints?

Comment: According to Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residually_finite_group#Profinite_topology), a group is residually finite iff its profinite topology is Hausdorff. According to Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_group#Properties_and_facts), a profinite group (one isomorphic to an inverse limit of finite groups) is automatically compact and Hausdorff. These facts might be relevant, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The statement is not true. The group of integers $\mathbf Z$ is residually finite.  On the other hand, consider the open sets $U_p\subseteq \mathbf Z$ defined by $U_p = p\mathbf Z$, where $p$ runs over the primes. Clearly $\{U_p\} \cup \{5 \mathbf{Z} +1\} \cup \{5 \mathbf{Z} -1\}$ is an open covering of $\mathbf Z$ (as any integer is either $\pm 1$ or divisible by *some* prime). But this covering has no finite sub-covering: by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, there is no *finite* set of primes such that each integer which is $\pm 2$ mod $5$ is divisible by one of those primes.

We can give a criterion. To say that $G$ is residually finite is to say that the canonical morphism $G \to \widehat{G}$ from $G$ to its profinite competion is *injective*. Thus, if $G$ is residually finite, $G$ embeds as a dense subgroup of the compact group $\widehat{G}$. Since $\widehat{G}$ is Hausdorff and compact, $G$ will be compact precisely when it is closed in $\widehat{G}$ - which is to say, precisely when $G=\widehat{G}$.

(Thanks to studiosus for pointing out my earlier mistake. My mistake lied in the silly statement that open subsets of profinite groups are closed - which is false. Open *subgroups* are closed, but open subsets need not be closed! For instance, the complement of a point in an infinite profinite group is obviously not closed.)

Comment: This is a completely wrong answer: Since $\hat{G}$ is Hausdorff, its dense proper subset cannot be closed, hence, cannot be compact. The mistake in the proof is the implication: If $\cup_i U_i$ contains $G$ then $\cup_i U_i=\hat{G}$. This implication is obviously false (just think about the set of nonzero real numbers as a subset in $R$.

Comment: Compact subsets of Hausdorff spaces are closed. Thus, if $G$ were compact, it would be also closed, hence, would equal $\hat{G}$, which is, in general, not the case.

Comment: Dear Bruno: As a more relevant example with an open covering, consider the Cantor set $C$ and $X\subset C$, the complement to one point. Then $X$ is open (and, of course, not closed!), but the open covering $\{X\}$ of $X$ clearly does not cover $C$. What confuses you is the fact that each TD space admits a basis consisting of clopen subsets.

Comment: @studiosus You are right, I found my mistake. I am fixing it right now. Thanks!

Comment: Really a nice answer! Thanks!

Comment: If may I, I have a question on the answer. I understand that $G$ embedd in the profinite completion,  but I cannot see why the embedding is an open map (we need this to infer the compactness of $G$, right?).

Comment: One can add that $G$ is compact in profinite topology if and only if $G$ is finite. The entire question, I think, stems from confusion between "compact" and "Hausdorff".

Comment: Really nice discussion and everybody learned something! +1from me, Bruno and Studiosus!

Comment: @studiosus "$G$ is compact in the profinite topology iff $G$ is finite." is wrong, it should be "$G$ is compact  iff it coincides with its profinite completion."

Comment: The example in the post can be simplified to $\{U_p\}\cup\{1+2\mathbb{Z}\}$ and one does not need the Chinese remainder theorem. Just take 2 times a "large" prime.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's several years late, but based on some of the comments on Bruno Joyal's answer, I thought it would be helpful to further clarify some details.

Suppose $G$ is a residually finite group. We consider $G$ as a topological group in the profinite topology. In the answer, it is stated that "$G$ embeds as a dense subgroup of $\hat{G}$". It is worth clarifying that this use of the word "embeds" is indeed in the topological sense.

**Proposition.** Let $f\colon G\to\hat{G}$ be the canonical embedding. Then $f$ is a homeomorphism between $G$ and $f(G)$ (with the subspace topology from $\hat{G}$).

*Proof.* It suffices to fix a coset $C$ of some normal finite-index subgroup $H$ of $G$, and find an open set $U\subseteq\hat{G}$ such that $f(G)\cap U=f(C)$. Viewing elements of $\hat{G}$ as sequences $(C_N)_{N\in\mathcal{N}}\in \prod_{\mathcal{N}}G/N$, where $\mathcal{N}$ is the collection of normal finite-index subgroups of $G$, we can take $U=\{(C_N)\in \hat{G}:C_H=C\}$.

So to simplify terminology, we view $G$ as a subgroup of $\hat{G}$, and the profinite topology on $G$ as the subspace topology induced from $\hat{G}$.   The relevant result is:

**Theorem.** The following are equivalent.

1. $G$ is compact in the profinite topology.
2. $G$ is closed in $\hat{G}$.
3. $G$ is open in $\hat{G}$.
4. $G=\hat{G}$.
5. The canonical embedding of $G$ into $\hat{G}$ is a homeomorphism.

*Proof.* 
(1) implies (2). If $G$ is compact in the profinite topology then (by the Proposition) $G$ is a compact set in $\hat{G}$. Since $\hat{G}$ is Hausdorff, $G$ is closed.

(2) implies (4). Trivial, since $G$ is dense in $\hat{G}$.

(4) implies (5). Immediate from the Proposition.

(5) implies (1). Immediate from compactness of $\hat{G}$.

(4) implies (3). Trivial.

(3) implies (2). Any open subgroup of a topological group is closed.

Some final remarks motivated by the comments on the accepted answer.

- In general, $G$ is not necessarily open in $\hat{G}$, and so the canonical embedding of $G$ into $\hat{G}$ is not necessarily an open map (this was asked in a comment by W4cc0).
- Since $\mathbb{Z}\neq\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$, it follows from the Theorem that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not compact in the profinite topology (Bruno Joyal also gave an explicit demonstration). The same holds for *any* countably infinite residually finite group, since there are no countably infinite compact Hausdorff groups (see [this link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4939/is-there-a-compact-group-of-countably-infinite-cardinality)).
- As pointed out by user 59363, it is *not* the case that $G$ is compact in the profinite topology if and only if $G$ is finite (which is claimed in a comment by Moishe Cohen). For example, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a topologically finitely generated pro-$p$ group, and hence $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}_p}=\mathbb{Z}_p$ (this follows from a result of Serre, which was generalized to any topologically finitely generated profinite group by Nikolov and Segal).